# extracting text from xml with Xcode

Tags: objective-c, xml, xcode, extract

I'm traying to extract info from a table made in xml, here is an example of mi file testXML.xml, it is inside the app:

```
<response>
<responseCode>0</responseCode>

<rows>
    <row>
        <user>1969-01-01</user>
        <score>1.5434126596E-2</score>
    </row>
    <row>
        <user>1969-02-01</user>
        <score>1.5489521629000001E-2</score>
    </row>
    <row>
        <user>1969-03-01</user>
        <score>1.5504809914E-2</score>
    </row>   < /rows>   </response>
```

what I'm trying to do is, to write in a text field the user, search it in the xml and display the score from the same row in a label. help please :S

Comment: are you writing the xml yourself in the app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok...so i suggest to use a NSDictionary instead

```
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]  init];
[dict setObject:@"score1" forKey:@"user1"]; //to set data in the dictionary
.....
```

to get data from dict:

```
[dict objectForKey:@"user1"];
```

to save to file:

```
[dict writeToFile:[[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"dictionary"] atomically:YES];
```

to read from file:

```
NSMutableDictionary *dict =[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:[[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"dictionary"]];
```

its easyer..it searches automatically, its fast

i dont see why you would use a xml over a dictionary in this case

Comment: in my xml there are  over 500 users and scores, wouldn't that be a problem?

Comment: not at all..dictionary is design to work with thousands of entrys + its speed optimized ...so thats good

Comment: well..the init part..where you want to initialize it, the setobjects...where you set the values of the objects, then i assume you want to save to file, and read from file when you want to search some values...search on google there are a lot of different examples on this..with sample project to see how it works

Comment: also..its always a good idea to read Apple's class reference https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003648